# Ошибка Attribute error, при выполнении connection.execute()

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, консоль, psycopg2

Код функции:

```py
def create_tables():
    with connection:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            connection.execute(CREATE_MOVIES_TABLE)
            connection.execute(CREATE_USERS_TABLE)
            connection.execute(CREATE_WATCHED_TABLE)
            connection.execute(CREATE_RELEASE_INDEX)
```

Лог ошибки:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Python+PostgreSQL_2.0\movies\app.py", line 19, in <module>
    database.create_tables()
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Python+PostgreSQL_2.0\movies\database.py", line 49, in create_tables
    connection.execute(CREATE_MOVIES_TABLE)
AttributeError: 'psycopg2.extensions.connection' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

Comment: cursor.execute(CREATE_MOVIES_TABLE)

Comment: with connection.cursor() as cursor:

такой вариант точно возможен, потому ошибка должна быть не прямо в этом

Comment: ошибка в том, что у connection нет метода execute, попробуйте вместо connection.execute использовать cursor.execute

Comment: Вы правы, это я осмотрелся

Comment: да, ит воркс...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> AttributeError: 'psycopg2.extensions.connection' object has no
> attribute 'execute'

Ошибка в том, что у `connection` нет метода `execute`, попробуйте вместо `connection.execute` использовать `cursor.execute`:

```py
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(CREATE_MOVIES_TABLE)
    cursor.execute(CREATE_USERS_TABLE)
    cursor.execute(CREATE_WATCHED_TABLE)
    cursor.execute(CREATE_RELEASE_INDEX)
```